# Could not find 'cocoapods' (>= 0) among N total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)

Tags: ruby, macos, xcode7, cocoapods

When I am trying to `pod install`, getting following issue:

```
Faizs-MBP:newj faizfareed$ pod install
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:315:in `to_specs': Could not find 'cocoapods' (>= 0) among 50 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/Users/faizfareed/.gem/ruby/2.0.0:/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0:/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0', execute `gem env` for more information
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:324:in `to_spec'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:64:in `gem'
    from /usr/local/bin/pod:22:in `<main>'
Faizs-MBP:newj faizfareed$
```

You can also find attached [detailed image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtoP5.png) for above error.

Could anyone sort out this issue???

---

I've followed your instructions & uninstalled all gem. but when I tried to install cocoapods it is giving following error.

[image]

Please advice. . .

Thanks

Comment: Did you install `cocoapods` gem?

Comment: yes I installed its latest version

Comment: If you are on OS X El Cap you should see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32891965/error-while-executing-gem-errnoeperm-operation-not-permitted

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Finally I got Solution For installation of CocoaPods in OS X El Capitan

First remove or uninstall all available Gems by using following command in your terminal(which is located in your Launchpad>Other>Terminal   or you can also find that in Finder>Applications>Utilities>Terminal)

```
gem uninstall --all
sudo gem uninstall --all
```

When after successful uninstallation of all Gems, Then write following command in your terminal

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
pod setup
```

Hope all of you will be awaiting for this answer. anyway, this works for me hence according to me it is best suitable solution to that particular problem.

Comment: i am also face the very same issue but when i follow your steps it gives me a warning  no such name (https://api.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/cocoapods-1.0.1.gemspec.rz)

Comment: The only way it eventually worked for me was
1. Uninstall all
2. Search entire Mac for cocoapods and delete
3. Restart Mac
4. Install cocoapods

Answer (score 10):

I used `brew` because this commands doesn't work for me. (I had some linking errors).

Anyway:

`brew uninstall cocoapods`

`brew install cocoapods`

> Warning: cocoapods 1.2.1 is already installed, it's just not linked.

`brew link cocoapods`

Done. Worked for me

Comment: Not sure. But when I run brew link cocoapods. The issues happened again.

Answer (score 6):

This is a ruby gems related problem. Usually, it happens when it "knows" there is a gem, but it can't find it. It might have been caused by different problems (you are in different version of ruby or a PATH has not been updated after some ruby/gem update related manipulations or gems installed using old cocoapods version and now you are trying to run a new version of pods or some other problem). If I can remember it correctly pods has changed where it saves the gems at some (0.2 -> 0.3) version.

Anyhow, here is old [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29382618/52317) that might help you.

```
# Uninstall all available gems
gem uninstall --all
sudo gem uninstall --all

# Reinstall cocoapods
sudo gem install cocoapods

# == RELAUNCH == terminal window and run
pod setup
```

Comment: is it ok to uninstall all available gems? I mean is there any required gem other than cocoapods which can cause most essential part of macbook's performance? ??
or it is just for cocoapods? & zero percent risk for uninstalling & reinstalling gem?

Comment: I also tried to uninstall cocoapods & it works perfectly but when after that I tried to re-install cocoapods it was not recognizing the path & also was giving me error that you've no permission to perform this task.  & I followed different forums & used to get help via different sources & now finally installed latest version of cocoapds 1.0.0

Comment: But I am 70% satisfied with your answer that there must be multiple versions & hence I should uninstall all & re-install all gem... 
But I needs surety that there must be no side effects....

Comment: After following your instructions, all gems are successfully installed now. but when I I tried to install cocoa pods again but it is giving error which I've edited my above question please review & advice me

Answer (score 2):

i installed the New mac OSX Sierra (10.12) and trying to update the cocoapod using the  the same steps as mention above  but getting  this error

```
Error installing cocoapods: activesupport requires Ruby version >= 2.2.2
```

now finally i get a chance  to solve this  issue  I installed the Ruby 2.2.4 version instead...

in order to installed latest ruby follow these command

```
rvm install 2.2
rvm use 2.2
```

once the ruby is installed in your system  do these steps

```
sudo gem install activesupport -v 4.2.6
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

//Relaunch Terminal

```
pod setup
```

now finally i resolved the issue and successfully installed the cocoapod without any error .

Answer (score 1):

I faced exactly same error on MacOSX Sierra, but accepted answer didn't help, updating ruby with `rvm` helped though:

Open terminal and run

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

restart terminal

run `rvm list known` to find which is the latest version and install it using `rvm install ruby-2.4.1` (latest as of now)

check ruby version in terminal by `ruby -v`, if it still shows you `ruby 2.0.` run  `rvm use ruby-2.4.1`.

to set this as the default version, run `rvm use ruby-2.4.1 --default`

Answer (score 1):

```
bundle install
```

followed by

```
pod install
```

did the trick for me.