# Could not find 'minitest' (~> 5.1) among 42 total gem(s) (Gem::MissingSpecError)

Tags: ruby, react-native, rubygems, cocoapods, podfile

I am new to using React Native and is currently trying to make a simple to-do list. Unfortunately, I cannot proceed rn as I am stuck with this error, which I have no idea how to fix.

What happened?

- My react native worked fine until today because of a build failure due to 'RangeError - integer 4294967288 too big to convert to `int' (https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/10651).
- I accidentally did `sudo rm -rf /Library/Ruby/Gems/*` while trying to solve the previous issue.
- Now, every time I do pod install, I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> 16: from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1_1/libexec/bin/pod:23:in `<main>' 15: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:301:in` activate_bin_path'
> 14: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:301:in `synchronize' 13: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:302:in` block in activate_bin_path'
> 12: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1372:in `activate' 11: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1390:in` activate_dependencies'
> 10: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1390:in `each' 9: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1408:in` block in activate_dependencies'
> 8: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1372:in `activate' 7: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1390:in` activate_dependencies'
> 6: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1390:in `each' 5: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1408:in` block in activate_dependencies'
> 4: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1372:in `activate' 3: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1390:in` activate_dependencies'
> 2: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1390:in `each' 1: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1402:in` block in activate_dependencies'
> /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:311:in `to_specs': Could not find 'minitest' (~> 5.1) among 42 total gem(s) (Gem::MissingSpecError) Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/Users/XXX/.gem/ruby/2.6.0:/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0:/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1_1/libexec:/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0' , execute` gem env` for more information

`gem list`:

> *** LOCAL GEMS ***
> abbrev (default: 0.1.0)
> actioncable (6.1.4)
> actionmailbox (6.1.4)
> actionmailer (6.1.4)
> actionpack (6.1.4)
> actiontext (6.1.4)
> actionview (6.1.4)
> activejob (6.1.4)
> activemodel (6.1.4)
> activerecord (6.1.4)
> activestorage (6.1.4)
> activesupport (6.1.4)
> base64 (default: 0.1.0)
> benchmark (default: 0.1.1)
> bigdecimal (default: 3.0.0)
> builder (3.2.4)
> bundler (2.2.24)
> cgi (default: 0.2.0)
> concurrent-ruby (1.1.9)
> crass (1.0.6)
> csv (default: 3.1.9)
> date (default: 3.1.0)
> dbm (default: 1.1.0)
> debug (default: 0.1.0)
> delegate (default: 0.2.0)
> did_you_mean (default: 1.5.0)
> digest (default: 3.0.0)
> drb (default: 2.0.4)
> english (default: 0.7.1)
> erb (default: 2.2.0)
> erubi (1.10.0)
> etc (default: 1.2.0)
> fcntl (default: 1.0.0)
> ffi (1.15.3)
> fiddle (default: 1.0.6)
> fileutils (default: 1.5.0)
> find (default: 0.1.0)
> forwardable (default: 1.3.2)
> getoptlong (default: 0.1.1)
> globalid (0.4.2)
> i18n (1.8.10)
> io-console (default: 0.5.7)
> io-nonblock (default: 0.1.0)
> io-wait (default: 0.1.0)
> ipaddr (default: 1.2.2)
> irb (default: 1.3.5)
> json (default: 2.5.1)
> logger (default: 1.4.3)
> loofah (2.10.0)
> mail (2.7.1)
> marcel (1.0.1)
> matrix (default: 0.3.1)
> method_source (1.0.0)
> mini_mime (1.1.0)
> minitest (5.2.0, 5.1.0)
> mutex_m (default: 0.1.1)
> net-ftp (default: 0.1.2)
> net-http (default: 0.1.1)
> net-imap (default: 0.1.1)
> net-pop (default: 0.1.1)
> net-protocol (default: 0.1.0)
> net-smtp (default: 0.2.1)
> nio4r (2.5.7)
> nkf (default: 0.1.0)
> nokogiri (1.11.7 x86_64-darwin)
> observer (default: 0.1.1)
> open-uri (default: 0.1.0)
> open3 (default: 0.1.1)
> openssl (default: 2.2.0)
> optparse (default: 0.1.0)
> ostruct (default: 0.3.1)
> pathname (default: 0.1.0)
> power_assert (1.2.0)
> pp (default: 0.1.0)
> prettyprint (default: 0.1.0)
> prime (default: 0.1.2)
> pstore (default: 0.1.1)
> psych (default: 3.3.0)
> racc (default: 1.5.1)
> rack (2.2.3)
> rack-test (1.1.0)
> rails (6.1.4)
> rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
> rails-html-sanitizer (1.3.0)
> railties (6.1.4)
> rake (13.0.3)
> rbs (1.0.4)
> rdoc (default: 6.3.1)
> readline (default: 0.0.2)
> readline-ext (default: 0.1.1)
> reline (default: 0.2.5)
> resolv (default: 0.2.0)
> resolv-replace (default: 0.1.0)
> rexml (3.2.5)
> rinda (default: 0.1.0)
> rss (0.2.9)
> rubygems-update (3.2.24)
> securerandom (default: 0.1.0)
> set (default: 1.0.1)
> shellwords (default: 0.1.0)
> singleton (default: 0.1.1)
> sprockets (4.0.2)
> sprockets-rails (3.2.2)
> stringio (default: 3.0.0)
> strscan (default: 3.0.0)
> syslog (default: 0.1.0)
> tempfile (default: 0.1.1)
> test-unit (3.3.7)
> thor (1.1.0)
> time (default: 0.1.0)
> timeout (default: 0.1.1)
> tmpdir (default: 0.1.2)
> tracer (default: 0.1.1)
> tsort (default: 0.1.0)
> typeprof (0.12.0)
> tzinfo (2.0.4)
> un (default: 0.1.0)
> uri (default: 0.10.1)
> weakref (default: 0.1.1)
> websocket-driver (0.6.5, 0.6.3)
> websocket-extensions (0.1.5)
> yaml (default: 0.1.1)
> zeitwerk (2.4.2)
> zlib (default: 1.1.0)

What I did:
`bundle install` -> Gemfile not found so I did `bundle init` at the ios file and modified the gem file (but it didn't work)

> source "https://rubygems.org" gem 'rails', '~> 6.1.4' gem 'minitest', '~> 5.1' gem 'websocket-driver', '~> 0.6.5'

Would appreciate any help to fix this issue or restart so I can use React Native again.

Comment: Solved using solution from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37361452/could-not-find-cocoapods-0-among-n-total-gems-gemloaderror/45297188.