# Uninstall gems using Brew on macOS (Due to having a permission issue while doing sudo gem uninstall --all)

Tags: ruby, cocoa, rubygems, cocoapods, homebrew

While pod installing in a directory, error below shows up:

```
Could not find 'minitest' (>= 5.1) among 39 total gem(s) (Gem::MissingSpecError)
```

I have found a solution from [Could not find 'cocoapods' (>= 0) among N total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37361452/could-not-find-cocoapods-0-among-n-total-gems-gemloaderror/45297188). But the post says; "*delete gems using sudo gem uninstall --all*" which doesnt work for me due to having following error.

```
You don't have write permissions for the /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0 directory.
```

I had this permission issue before while using "*sudo gem install cocoapods*" and solved it by installing cocoapods using **HomeBrew**.

So now what I'm trying to do is deleting gems using brew to not to have that **permission** issue again.

Tried to do *brew uninstall gem*, but brew doesnt know what gem is. What can I do to uninstall gems using brew or to uninstall the gems without getting a permission error?

Thanks

Comment: What OS are you running?  The system partition in the current versions are read-only, so you should only need to restore `/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0`, which just needs admin access - do you have a backup?